# Send HTTP Request to NodeJS from Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, email

I am trying to figure out how can I send email from Angular 4.
I have NodeJS configured and also created account with mailgun.

My request file

```
var headers = new Headers(); 
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa("api:key-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
var url="https://api.mailgun.net/v3/DOMAIN.mailgun.org.mailgun.org/messages";
var mail = {
  from : "text",
  to : "text",
  subject : "text",
  text : "text"
};
this._http.post(url, message, {headers:authHeader});
```

I do not understand how to connect Angular with Node js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer that was provided and accepted was for AngularJS (1.x). There is simply no `$scope`, `module()`, or `controller()` in Angular 2+.

Adding headers to a POST, from the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#headers):

```
let message = {
  from : "text",
  to : "text",
  subject : "text",
  text : "text"
};

this.http.post('/some/api/path', JSON.stringify(message), {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', "Basic " + btoa("api:key-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
})
.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Or using the [HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) object:

```
let foo: string = btoa("api:key-XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': "Basic " + foo )});

this.http.post('/some/api/path', JSON.stringify(message), { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

The previous examples are for Angular 4+ [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http), if you are using Angular 2.x and [HttpModule](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html), then you can approach it like [this](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#headers) using `Headers` and `RequestOptions`:

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

let message = { /* ... */ };

let foo: string = btoa("api:key-XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': "Basic " + foo )});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.post('/some/api/path', JSON.stringify(message), options)
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Now i am getting this error:"Argument of type 'Headers' is not assignable to parameter of type "RequestOptions"'               
export class Enrollment        Component {
  constructor(protected http: Http) {
    let foo: string = btoa("api:key-XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': "Basic " + foo });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.post('/some/api/path', JSON.stringify(message), options)
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));

Comment: It sounds like you may be using HttpModule, rather than the Angular 4+ HttpClientModule. You'll need to use `RequestOptions` with `Headers`, instead. I've updated the answer to demonstrate this. Hope that helps!

Comment: I am getting an error : 'from' parameter is missing.                     message mwssage= {
    from : 'email@gmail.com',
    to : 'email@gmail.com',
    subject : 'text',
    text : 'text',
    multipart : true};
    foo: string = btoa("api:key-xxxxxxxx");
    headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': "Basic " + this.foo });
    send(){    this.http.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxc.mailgun.org/messages', JSON.stringify(this.message), { headers: this.headers })
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res));

Comment: You may need to post a separate question as this was regarding HTTP headers. It's not clear when exactly you are seeing this error. My guess would be that `this.message` is undefined/empty. You need to make sure you are doing `this.message = { /* props */ }` when you are creating the object. Try doing `console.log(this.message)` prior to the POST and see if you have values, that would be a good place to start.